# What's the proper word between "over-rated" and "underrated"?

Tags: word-request

I am trying to find a word which lies between the meaning of **over-rated** and **underrated**.

What's the proper word between "**over-rated**" and "**underrated**"?

> Sentence: Recently, I saw Titanic (1997) movie, I feel it's neither over-rated nor
> underrated. I think it's --------------

Comment: I don't think any of the previous suggestions are correct, because they all address the quality of the object, whereas **over-rated** or **under-rated** are about people's perceptions of the object.  It might help if you could use it in a sentence to show what you're looking for.

Comment: @stangdon Sentence added. Yes, previous suggestion not I am looking for.

Comment: I think it has the right rating. [I recently saw the movie Titanic]

Comment: What is your understanding of the word "over-rated" and "underrated"? Are you trying to say the movie was neither bad nor great or are you trying to say you don't think the movie's reviews were too positive or too negative considering the content of the movie?

Comment: It's [okayish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/okayish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say that it was "assessed appropriately/correctly", "fine", or you could say that you agree with the rating.  But after you said that it was neither overrated nor underrated, you could opt to say nothing else.

P.S.  In American English "overrated" is one word.